# Any video player other than VLC to add background to subtitles?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player, subtitle

The title is saying it all: I would like a player other than VLC to play videos that have embedded subs and hide these under my own + a background.

[image]

I use VLC much more often than I have this need for subtitle background, and, as adding removing & background in VLC is not instant, I would like to have a separate player for this rare case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### MPV

As expected, `mpv` has a CLI [option](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-sub-back-color) (`--sub-back-color=<color>`) that can be used to start a separate instance with subtitle background. For example:

```
mpv --sub-back-color=#131415 path/to/video
```

Editing applications menu, a new entry can be added:

[image]

[image]

---

Such commands can be used with MPV front-ends, like Haruna (see below for supplementary options to toggle etc), SMPlayer, Celluloid.

---

### SMPLAYER

Those arguments can be used with SMPlayer:

[image]

---

### Celluloid

[image]

---

### The subs background can be made transparent.

`CC` is the value to be added before the 6-digit color number in order to set a 80% opacity level (e.g. for black: `#CC000000`). See all such values [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/6590#issuecomment-1400100661).

---

### Haruna

Haruna can take better advantage of this possibility, because it has the option to trigger the background with a shortcut (without restarting the player) using a somewhat different custom command to be added to its configuration settings (of the form `set sub-back-color #xxxxxx`). Thus, with different shortcuts different colors and/or transparency levels can be triggered, while another shortcut can be used to remove the background by setting a 100% transparency (0% opacity) level (`00`):

[image]